# Creating a trigger for a value that can change

Tags: mysql

I have created a table where it shows the total number of hours spent reading.

```
CREATE TABLE total_hours (
total_hours int,
last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO total_hours(total_hours)
SELECT SUM(hours) FROM users;
```

Now I want to create a trigger that always updates the total_hours in the table "total_hours" if new data about hours are added or modified in the "users" table.
This is what I tried:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER total_hours_check
AFTER UPDATE ON users FOR hours
BEGIN
INSERT INTO total_hours (total_hours)
SELECT SUM(hours)
FROM users
END;
// DELIMITER ;
```

But something feels wrong with it, as well as, it gives me syntax error. I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `FOR hours` should be `FOR EACH ROW`. You also need a `;` after `FROM users`

Comment: @Nick Thank you so much! It did work perfectly!